# Rikulo built using JQuery not itself?

Tags: dart, rikulo

I'm wondering,

In definition Rikulo

> Rikulo is a free and open source Dart framework for creating incredible cross-platform web and native mobile applications using HTML5.

But why the web is built by JQuery not itself?

Is that Rikulo is to young yet so it builts with JQuery?

BTW, the "compiler" Dart Editor use a lot of RAM ~500M it cost a lot!!!

Comment: The Dart "editor" is actually an IDE, offering much more facilities than a simple IDE. AFAIK, it is based on Eclipse, which never was cheap on memory... I don't see a real question in your post, such wondering should be written directly to Rikulo's authors, or its mailing list, if it has one. Note also that a Web site isn't a Web application, they don't have the same constraints.

Comment: Additionally, you can download the Dart-SDK as a separate component which will just provide you with the virtual machine, libraries, and dart2js compiler without the Dart Editor itself. It is all CLI based. See the dart download page, choose your platform and choose the SDK download instead. http://www.dartlang.org/downloads.html

Comment: I though Dart can use for building web page, LOL!It might be!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rikulo is written in Dart, not JS, so jQuery is not applicable here. IMO, Dart's API covers well what jQuery provides, though Dart is young and not as stable as jQuery yet.